# Send E mail to an user at a specific day every time in php (Yii framework)

Tags: php, email, yii

I am new at `php` and using `Yii` framework.currently I am facing a problem how to send a mail to an user. I have a table which has a date field which indicates when the e mail needs to be sent. This date field is not the same for every user. When the date time comes the system will send a mail to the specific user. How can I do this. If anybody can give me some code example,that will be much more helpful. I do not want to use corn job. Need some code example.

Table:

```
User_id  job_title_id   cv_type  review_date       status
A        B              C        16/05/2015        yes
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: I don't think it is possible without using a cron, you need to execute a php script on a minute, hourly, daily time frame in order to work.

Comment: Thanks @AkhilThayyil  for your suggestion.I will try to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest a cron job (linux) or task scheduler (windows) are specially useful for these kind of situations and I **highly recommend** you to use these builtin OS features but since you asked otherwise here I go:

A possible solution in php would be to create an infinite loop with a [sleep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) in it like:

```
while(true){
    try{
        // Here should be the actual functionality to check the database
        // and send e-mails to the specific user(s) if needed.
    } catch(\Exception $e) { //this try catch exists to catch all exceptions that could crash this script.
        echo $e->getMessage(); 
        //notify yourself (by email) that an error has occurred 
    }

    sleep(60*60); //In this case 1 hour sleep 60 seconds * 60 = 60 minutes
}
```

The downside is that you'll have to **manually start** the job once, that is if the world was prefect... But since the script could run into an PHP fatal error or server reboot you'll have to **manually reboot** this script each time. To start the script in linux do something as the following:

```
nohup php script_name.php >> error.log & // nohup prevents the script from being closed when you exit the terminal
```